# SearchView not appearing on Floating Action Button click

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, searchview, floating-action-button

How can I open a `SearchView` widget from Floating Action Button? It seems weird that there appears to be no obvious way of open it outside a menu item. I tried using `val searchView = search.expandActionView(search)` but that didn't work.

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var mAdapter: AdapterServiceUpdates
    private val arrayItems = ArrayList<ItemCompany>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.collapsingtoolbar_and_recyclerview)

        val mCollapsingToolbarLayout = findViewById<CollapsingToolbarLayout>(R.id.myCollapsingToolbarLayout)
        val mToolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.myToolbar)
        val mRecyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.myRecyclerView)

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar)
        mCollapsingToolbarLayout.title = "MainActivity"
        mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener { onBackPressed() }

        val mFab: View = findViewById(R.id.myFab)
        mFab.setOnClickListener { view -> ?
        }

        arrayItems.add(ItemCompany("Item A"))
        arrayItems.add(ItemCompany("Item B"))
        arrayItems.add(ItemCompany("Item C"))
        arrayItems.add(ItemCompany("Item D"))
        arrayItems.add(ItemCompany("Item E"))
        arrayItems.add(ItemCompany("..."))

        mRecyclerView.layoutManager =
                androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager(this)

        val mListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { _, _, _, _ -> }
        mAdapter = MyAdapter(this, arrayItems, true)

        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(
                androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration(
                        this,
                        LinearLayout.VERTICAL
                )
        )
        mRecyclerView.adapter = mAdapter
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu)
        val search = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
        val searchView = search.expandActionView(search)

        // val searchView = search.actionView as SearchView
        searchView.queryHint = "Search"
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                return false
            }
            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                mAdapter.filter.filter(newText)
                return true
            }
        })
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            android.R.id.home -> {
                val intent = parentActivityIntent
                intent?.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION)
                onBackPressed()
                true
            }

            else ->
                super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`searchView.setIconified(false)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView#setIconified(boolean)) within the FAB `OnClickListener` callback to open the `SearchView`

> How can I do it on class level when Android is expecting it to be
> declared as an options menu item?

You can use a lateinit var in the class level as below (notice the changes marked with `//<<<<<<< change here` notation

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var searchView: SearchView //<<<<<<< change here
    ...

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.collapsingtoolbar_and_recyclerview)

        // rest of your code .....

        val mFab: View = findViewById(R.id.myFab)
        mFab.setOnClickListener { view -> ?
            searchView?.setIconified(false) //<<<<<<< change here
        }


    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu)
        val searchItem: MenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
        searchView = searchItem.getActionView() as SearchView ///<<<<<<< change here

        //  ....
        // .... rest of onCreateOptionsMenu() method
```

Comment: How can I access `searchView` from the FAB?

Comment: nope, call it whenever you want to open the `SearchView` . in Your case it's on Floating Action Button click; so you need to define the `searchView` on class level so that you can call it within the FAB callback using `searchView.setIconified(false)`

Comment: How can I do it on class level when Android is expecting it to be declared as an options menu item?

Comment: @Swarthy46 .. excuse me, dropped it as `MenuItem` while it's `SearchView` .. the updated answer should work now

Comment: `lateinit property search has not been initialized` + should `search` be `searchView`?

Comment: yeah it's `seachView`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225007/discussion-between-zain-and-swarthy46).

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion for you is

```
//class level
private val fab
   get() = findViewById(R.id.fab)

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
   menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu)
   val searchItem: MenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)

   if (searchItem != null) {
      searchView = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem) as SearchView
   fab.setOnClickListener{_->
       searchView.setIconified(false)
   }
   //....
}
```

Just try this to expand the SearchView

```
searchView.setIconified(false)
```

and collapse it

```
searchView.setIconified(true)
```

**Important!**

You should change the value of android:showAsAction from ifRoom|collapseActionView to always

I hope that's helpful for you

Comment: `searchView` will be unresolved because of the location of the Floating Action Button's code. Should this be moved? Bear in the mind that the search icon on the top-right of screen should not be showing.

Comment: You can declare fab on class level and then you can set the fab.setOnClickListener inside onCreateOptionsMenu